# How to get sampling points by rotating a direction in a for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, rotation, sampling, direction

I need to loop over a given number of sampling points. Those sampling points are normalized vectors representing directions. They should be calculate them in code. Starting with a forward vector `1, 0`, I want to rotate around the origin so that I came up with the given number of directions.

```
for(int i = 0; i < number_of_sampling_points; ++i)
{
    // get direction vector based on i and number_of_sampling_points
    // ...
}
```

For example, with `number_of_sampling_points` is `4` inside the loop I want to get the value pairs `1, 0`, `0, 1`, `-1, 0`, `0, -1`. The order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
const int number_of_sampling_points = 4;
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_sampling_points; ++i)
{
    const double a = PI * 2 * (1.0 - i) / number_of_sampling_points;

    double x = sin(a);
    double y = cos(a);

    cout << "(" << x << " , " << y << ")" << endl;
}
```

Output (rounded):

```
(1 , 0)
(0 , 1)
(-1 , 0)
(0 , -1)
```

Comment: What does `1.0 - i` make a different to Pubby's solution? He just casts `i` to double but doesn't subtract it from `1`. Moreover, is there a meaningful name for you variable `a`? What does it represent?

Comment: `1.0 - i` makes the order of the result as you wrote (however you said it doesn't matter). The name `a` is not special thing, I used `a` to make my code more readable (in my opinion).

Answer (score 2):

Use trig:

```
double x = std::cos(pi * 2 * (double)i / (double)number_of_sampling_points);
double y = std::sin(pi * 2 * (double)i / (double)number_of_sampling_points);
```